# vCard-editor for windows

Tags: windows, gratis, vcard

To manage some contacts on an mobile device I need an editor to create some vCard-files. The current source can export vcf-files in a very uncomfortable way and wrong format, so I have to edit each of them anyway. So I want to write them new, it's faster. But I need a program (gratis) to do this.

Comment: Did you know if you have a gmail account you can import/export a vCard file directly from there?

Comment: It seems you want an `offline` one, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Thunderbird with [MoreFunctionsForAddressBook](https://freeshell.de/~kaosmos/morecols-en.html) addon for this.

Another solution is [DoubleContact](https://github.com/DarkHobbit/doublecontact/)

Comment: you should have been mentioned DoubleContact is Linux-only, and OP deliberately mentioned Windows via tag

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with a similar issue (I had problems in name encoding, versioning and some additional attributes) and I finally ended up writing [my own tool](https://github.com/kubow/vcf_editor), that is based on:

- python 3+
- [TkInter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html?highlight=tkinter#module-tkinter) (aka GUI for python)
- [vObject](https://eventable.github.io/vobject/) library that can manage contact cards as well as calendar events

With a very little effort (in case you fairly know python language), you can write either a small script (that goes through files in directory and repairs them - or even creates them from a scratch) or you could implement/change a button in my solution. If you would be more specific about the issue it has, maybe we can elaborate more.